# Css link not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, browser

i have a very annoying problem. i have made a design of my site using CSS and it seems to work perfectly in Google Chrome and IE but the CSS designing is not all working in Firefox. what Could be the problem , i tried lots of things its still not working.
As new users are not allowed to post the image. i m unable to explain with the screen shot.

My code in Index.php

```
     <!Doctype html>
     <html lang="en">
     <title>Online Voting RTC</title>
     <head>


     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="css\style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js\create_text_box.js">
     </script>

     </head>
     <body>
     <div id="wapper">
        <!-- Define Header -->
        <?php include("header.php"); ?>
        <!-- End Header -->

        <!-- Main content area -->
        <?php include("maincontent.php");?>
        <!-- End of Main content area -->

        <!-- Left Sidebar -->
        <?php include("sidebar.php");?>
        <!-- End Left Sidebar -->


        <!-- Footer -->
        <?php include("footer.php");?>
        <!-- End of Footer -->
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

This is the  Css portion

```
 body {
background: #ffffff;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
    background: #dddddd;
}

#header {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
float: left;
background: #403cf7;
}

.logo {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
}

.pagetitle {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:550px;
    top:20px;
}
 .usermenu {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    right:20px;
    top:20px;
 }

 #sidebar {
width: 20%;
height: 600px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
float: left;
background: #ffff99;
text-align: center;
  }

 #maincontent {
width: 80%;
height: 600px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
float: right;
background: #95dff8;
}

#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
    background: #272727;
}

/*-----------------------------------------CSS for navigation    Menu------------------------*/
  #navMenu{
color:#d4d3d3;
font-family:Geneva;
float:left;

 }

  #navMenu ul li a{

text-decoration:none;
color:#989694;
}

 #navMenu ul li a:hover{
color:#f46322;
}


 #navMenu ul{
padding:0;
 margin:0;
margin-left:25px;
list-style:none;
position:relative;
left:20px;
top:20px;
 }
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

i would be very grateful if someone can help me out in this case. Actually i was checking for browser compatibility, and i came across this problem. 
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: Please specify your exact problem.

Comment: try `<!DOCTYPE html>` as it's case sensitive

Comment: Try using forward slash "/" for your css js paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your link tag

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css" />
```

If your css folder is off the route dir of your site you would be better using

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="/css/style.css" />
```

as this will still work if you move your page to a different folder.

You also need to move your title tag within the HEAD element to make the HTML valid.

Comment: Using “ />” instead of “>” is neither required nor recommended in HTML5, which is what the page is using. It has nothing to do with the issue at hand. The note about the `title` element placement is correct but not relevant to the question. The suggestion to change the URL is questionable at best.

Answer (score 3):

The character “\” (backslash) is not allowed in a URL; change it to “/” (normal slash). Some browsers implicitly convert the incorrect “\” to “/”.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the type="text/css".

Your code should be look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Once I removed the z-index of -1 from the container  class. the links started working again.